# How to get numbers from string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a strings that can look like this:

```
left 10 top 50
```

How can i extract the numbers, while the numbers can range from 0 to 100 and words can be left/right top/bottom? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split and extract the 2nd and 4th tokens:

```
var arr = "left 10 top 50".split(" ");

var a = +arr[1];
var b = +arr[3];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
var text = "top 50 right 100 left 33";
var arr = text.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g);
console.log(arr); //Returns an array with "50", "100", "33"
```

You can also use `[\d+]` (digits) instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: This is how I'd do it, except because I'm lazy I'd just do `\d+`.

Comment: Ooooo this is neat. I love regex pattern but I never know what they'll do.

Answer (score 1):

Place this string in a var, if you know every number will be seperated by a space you can easely do the following:

```
var string = "top 50 left 100";
    // split at the empty space
    string.split(" ");
var numbers = new Array();
// run through the array
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    // check if the string is a number
    if(parseInt(string[i], 10)){
        // add the number to the results
        numbers.push(string[i]);
    }
}
```

Now you can wrap the whole bit in a function to run it at any time you want:

```
function extractNumbers(string){
    var temp = string.split(" ");
    var numbers = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(temp[i], 10)){
            numbers.push(temp[i]);
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

var myNumbers = extractNumbers("top 50 left 100");
```

### Update

After reading @AmirPopovich s answer, it helped me to improve it a bit more:

```
if(!isNaN(Number(string[i]))){
    numbers.push(Number(string[i]));
}
```

This will return any type of number, not just `Integers`. Then you could technically extend the string prototype to extract numbers from any string:

```
String.prototype.extractNumbers = function(){ /*The rest of the function body here, replacing the keyword 'string' with 'this' */ };
```

Now you can do `var result = "top 50 right 100".extractNumbers();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'left 10 top 50';
var splitted = str.split(' ');
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < splitted.length ; i++)
{
    var num = Number(splitted[i]);
    if(!isNaN(num) && num >= 0 && num <= 100){
        arr.push(num);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/mq1scksj/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = "left 10 top 50".split(" ");

var numbers;

for ( var index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++ ) {
    if ( !isNaN(myArray[index]))
       numbers= myArray[index]
}
```

find working example on the link below
http://jsfiddle.net/shouvik1990/cnrbv485/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it dynamically by different keywords try something like this:

```
var testString = "left 10 top 50";
var result = getNumber("top", testString);

function getNumber(keyword, testString) {
  var tmpString = testString;
  var tmpKeyword = keyword;

  tmpString = tmpString.split(tmpKeyword + " ");
  tmpString = tmpString[1].split(' ')[0];

  return tmpString;
}
```